# Python While loop only does first iteration

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, iteration

I'm a beginner and haven't programmed in python for a while but am making a program to keep track of all the books in my book club's library.

This is a function in the code and is supposed to allow me to store any new books added into json files containing dictionaries where the key is the book number and the value is the book title, **however it only does the first iteration then abruptly ends the program after the if/else statement regardless of what comes after.**

What have I done wrong?

```
print("\nEnter the titles of the added books, in order."
            "\nEnter 'stop' whenever you're finished.")
while True:
    #Assign book numbers as keys for each entry (book titles)
    book_number = len(all_books) + 1
    new = input("\n")
    title = new.lower().strip()
    if title == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        #Until user stops, add their entries to the dictionaries
        unread_books[book_number] = title
        all_books[book_number] = title
        continue
print("Saving Records...")
store_records()
print("Records Saved.")
```

I've tried it a few ways:

```
if title != 'stop':
    #Until user stops, add their entries to the dictionaries
    unread_books[book_number] = title
    all_books[book_number] = title
    continue
else:
    break
```

Like this as well:

```
if title == 'stop':
    break
if new:
    #Until user stops, add their entries to the dictionaries
    unread_books[book_number] = title
    all_books[book_number] = title
    continue
```

Also:

```
if title == 'stop':
    break
#Until user stops, add their entries to the dictionaries
unread_books[book_number] = title
all_books[book_number] = title
```

I am very confused.

Comment: It all depends on what you enter as input after starting the program.

Comment: The code works fine for me (after guessing you created dictionaries `all_books` and `unread_books` and removing the line which calls the nonexistent `store_records` function).

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've been testing by entering anything other than stop

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: @trincot I use Sublime Text and haven't been getting any error messages with these codes

Comment: Where is all_books declared?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've now tested a minimal reproducible example and it works if I define the blank dictionaries so I guess the problem is the code I have for loading the previously saved json files into the dictionaries at the start of the program

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using lists:

```
import pprint

all_books = []
unread_books = []

print("\nEnter the titles of the added books, in order."
            "\nEnter 'stop' whenever you're finished.")
while True:
    #Assign book numbers as keys for each entry (book titles)
    new = input("\n")
    title = new.lower().strip()
    if title == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        #Until user stops, add their entries to the dictionaries
        unread_books.append(title)
        all_books.append(title)
        continue

print("Saving Records...")
# ...
print("all_books: ")
pprint.pprint(all_books)
print("unread_books: ")
pprint.pprint(unread_books)
```

If you want to store an index / book number explicitly, you could use a dictionary or some other data type.

Comment: Yes I explicitly want to store the books in dictionaries with index numbers as the key, thanks to a comment I now know the problem is code not included in the post that retrieves previously stored json files to define the dictionaries